# How to create a Global Variable in elixir Module

Tags: elixir

I have the following code in elixir:

```
def get_trackerid(imei) do
  client = get_new_client()
  {:ok, result} = :cqerl.run_query(client, "SELECT * FROM trackers_by_imei where imei = \'#{imei}\';")
  row = :cqerl.all_rows(result)
end
```

Now, now many functions are calling get_trackerid function and everytime the function is called, a call to database is made.

Is there a way to write a function in elixir such the result is stored in a local variable. So, when the next time trackerid for the same imei is requested, I can get the data from the local variable itself.

I think there is no concept of global variable in elixir, so that is not an option, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a few options for saving state within Elixir.

If this method is part of a module that is running a [GenServer](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html), then you can use the `state` parameter to cache values.

You could also use an [ets table](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html) to cache the values. This would work both inside and outside a GenServer.

Comment: https://medium.com/elixirlabs/when-to-use-processes-in-elixir-18287da73d47 this can also be very helpful

Answer (score 8):

What you're asking about is called "[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)". I mention that if you care to Google and see if you can find more on the subject.

This is a great blog posting discussing a memoization technique in Elixir: https://web.archive.org/web/20161116091132/http://ineverfinishanyth.in/2014/01/20/memoization-in-elixir

**TL;DR**

> Construct a cache and check the cache when you try to do your computation to see if the answer is already there. In the case of that blog posting he constructs a key-value store as a cache but obviously what sort of cache you should construct will be highly dependent on the data you're caching.

Comment: Link provided is broken.

Comment: @tunedconsulting I've changed the link to point to the google cache version of the webpage.

Comment: the new link is here http://ineverfinishanyth.in/2014/01/20/memoization-in-elixir (:

Comment: I've modified the link to point to the internet archive copy of the link.  _Teach_a_man_to_fish_moment:  In the future, rather than complain that the link is broken maybe you could try to find the link on the internet archive yourself and update the entry.  Just a suggestion.